# Select rows with different conditions meanwhile all of them share the same key column

Tags: sql

I already have a working solution, but i'm looking for a faster or better way to do it.

```
key column | fruit | quantity
------------------------------
11111       apple       100
11111       melon        50
11111       banana       75
22222       apple       200
22222       cherry      100
22222       banana       10
33333       apple        90
33333       melon        60
33333       lemon       200
```

I want to see which key column's 'fruits' and 'quantities' are meeting my conditions.

My solution:

```
SELECT 
    a1.[key column]
FROM
    products a1,
    products a2,
    products a3
WHERE
    (a1.fruit = 'apple' and a1.quantity > 95) and
    (a2.fruit = 'melon' and a2.quantity > 40) and
    (a3.fruit = 'banana' and a3.quantity > 60) and
    (a1.[key column] = a2.[key column]) and 
    (a1.[key column] = a3.[key column])
```

When all conditions are meet, and they all share the same [key column] the result will be: 11111

If i understand it right, all am i doing is joining the same table 3x. It's already fast, but the table contains 500k lines, and i want to have more conditions. I'm not sure how smart is to join the same table 10 times, if i have 10 conditions.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago!) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT p.[key column]
FROM products p
WHERE (p.fruit = 'apple' and p.quantity > 95) or
      (p.fruit = 'melon' and p.quantity > 40) or
      (p.fruit = 'banana' and p.quantity > 60)
GROUP BY p.[key column]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) = 3;
```

Whether this is faster that your method depends on the database, data size, and indexes.  However, this method is consistent in performance . . . so adding more conditions has little effect on performance.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this solution is slower then mine, (~150 vs ~300ms), but way more simpler (easier to generate the query), so i went this yours, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need join. Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT [key column]
FROM
products 
WHERE quantity > CASE fruit WHEN 'apple' THEN 95
                 WHEN 'melon' THEN 40 
                 WHEN 'banana' THEN 60 END
```

Comment: Seems like OP wants all 3 fruits verified.